# how to configure the resources path when running an unzipped jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, resources

I have some resources folders in my intellij java project.

I have created a fat-jar with all the resources folders, but the folder's structure has changed:

I unzip the jar to run a `java` command.

Now all the resources folders are at the jar's root.

How can I change the code to located the resources folders differently when i run in intellij and when running unzipped jar?

I have tried this, but it won't work good:

```
public class Constants {

    public static final String RESOURCES_PATH = System.getProperty("resources_path",
            Constants.class.getClassLoader().getResource("html_pages").toString().replace("/html_pages",""));

    public static final String ROUTE_REQUESTS_URL_INPUT_FILE = RESOURCES_PATH+"/input/routing_nyc_11K_april16.log";
```

In run time I get this:

```
RESOURCES_PATH = file:/Users/me/workspace/Regression/build/resources/main/input/routing_nyc_11K_april16.log
```